# Number of subsets with $m$ elements of a set with $n$ elements is $\frac{n!}{m!}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I wonder if my proof of the statement in the title is correct:

Let $n,m\in\mathbb{N}: m<n$.

Let $X_n$ be a set with $n$ elements.

Let $A_m\subset X_n$ with $m$ elements.

Let $B_m$ be a set of all possible sets $A_m$.

$A_0=\emptyset\implies B_0=\{\emptyset\}\implies |B_0|=1$

$B_{m+1}=\{A_m\cup x\quad  \forall x\in A_m',\forall A_m\in B_m, \forall m\}$

$|A_m'|=|X_n|-|A_m|=n-m$

$|B_{m+1}|=|B_m|\times|x\in A_m'| = |B_m|\times|A_m'| = |B_m|\times(n-m)$

$|B_m|=1\cdot n\cdot (n-1)\cdot \dots \cdot (n-m)=\frac{n!}{m!}$

I suppose the idea is correct but my notation may be misleading or incorrect in some places.

Comment: The statement in the title is not correct, as one can see by taking $m=0$ and $n>0$ for example. The number of subsets with $m$ elements of an $n$-element set is the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) $\binom mn$.

Comment: Minor correction, it is $\pmatrix{n\\m}$.

Comment: You should always check a formula with at least one simple example, E.g. $m=1$ and $n\ge 3.$ Or look for a symmetry, e.g. $ B_m$ and $\{b': b\in B_m\}$ have the same number of members so $\binom {n}{m}=\binom {n}{n-m}.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the number of $m$-set elements from a set of $n$ elements (so indeed $m \le n$) is exactly $\binom{n}{m}$, almost by (the *semantic/combinatorial*) definition of the binomial coefficient.

If we pick a subset *in order*, we cannot re-use elements, so we have $n \times (n-1) \times \ldots$ ($m$ terms) choices, which is $\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}$ but then all $m!$ sequences that lead to *the same set* (which have no order) are identified, and so we divide by $m!$ again and so we get $$\frac{n!}{(n-m)!m!}$$ which is the *algebraic* definition of $\binom{n}{m}$.

Comment: Also see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) on this.